# Uploading with Dropbox API from VBA success but no file

Tags: excel, vba, upload, dropbox, dropbox-api

I'm trying to upload a .docx file (which is generated by an excel macro) to Dropbox via dropbox API (I cannot install dropbox client on my work PC so cannot simply save the file locally and have it sync automatically).

At the moment, the script is saving the file locally, now I'm trying to grab that file and upload it. (Step 2 will be to just upload it without saving locally, and I know I need to tidy up this code, but just trying to get it to work at this stage). It seems that all is ok, and the upload returns a 200 status (OK), but there is no file on my dropbox. Any suggestions?

```
Public Sub dropboxUpload()
'Public Sub dropboxUpload(FileName As String)
Dim req As MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60
Dim strFile As String
Dim Pos1 As Integer
Dim Pos2 As Integer
Set req = New MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60
Dim arg As String
Dim content As Byte
content = ReadByteArrFromFile("C:\Users\me\Desktop\Document Generator\document.docx")
arg = "{""path"":""/Work" & FileName & """,""mode"":{"".tag"":""add""},""autorename"":true,""mute"":false}"
req.Open "POST", "https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload", False
req.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
req.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/octet-stream"
req.setRequestHeader "Content-length", Len(Result)
req.setRequestHeader "Dropbox-API-Arg", arg
req.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "api-explorer-client"
req.Send strFile

If req.Status = 200 Then '200 = OK
    Debug.Print req.responseText
Else
    MsgBox req.Status & ": " & req.StatusText
    Debug.Print req.responseText
End If

End Sub

Function ReadByteArrFromFile(filePath) As Byte()
    Dim buff() As Byte
    Dim fileNumb As Integer
    fileNumb = FreeFile
    Open filePath For Binary Access Read As fileNumb
    ReDim buff(0 To LOF(fileNumb) - 1)
    Get fileNumb, , buff
    Close fileNumb
    ReadByteArrFromFile = buff
End Function
```

Comment: You're not using `content` anywhere after reading it from the file... Instead you're sending `strFile`

Comment: Thanks @TimWilliams that was an oversight in the post rather than the live code. When I get my Status 200 (OK) the responseText is `{"name": "Work (1)", "path_lower": "/work (1)", "path_display": "/Work (1)", "id": "id:xxx", "client_modified": "xxx", "server_modified": "xxx", "rev": "xxx", "size": 2, "is_downloadable": true, "content_hash": "xxx"}` and it keeps increasing the number after the `/Work` path each time I run the code. Not sure why it would be doing that, and there is still only the single folder on Dropbox.

Comment: I noticed that `FileName` isn't being defined anywhere, so I added `FileName= "/document.docx". All seems to be working, because I'm having a path conflict error now, meaning that the file is being detected by Dropbox but it's not showing on the dropbox website in the Work folder...

Comment: I discovered the problem, it's not uploading to Dropbox/Work, it's uploading to Dropbox/Apps/appName/Work. And they're in there! But document.docx is only 2 bites in size...

Comment: Created a new app with Full Access rather than Folder access so have fixed the upload location problem, but still have the file size problem at 2 bytes. That's off topic here so I'll ask a new question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68279552/vba-uploading-to-dropbox-but-tiny-file-size).