# Uploading to Dropbox but tiny file size

Tags: excel, vba, byte, dropbox, dropbox-api

I have a VBA function in Excel which creates a document.docx and then uploads it to Dropbox. It is successfully creating a file in Dropbox, but it can't be opened because it is only 2 bytes in size. Why is there no content in this file? I don't really know how files actually work, it it something to do with the script converting the content to bytes?

```
Public Sub dropboxUpload()
Dim req As MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60
Dim strFile As String
Dim Pos1 As Integer
Dim Pos2 As Integer
Set req = New MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60
Dim arg As String

Dim content As Byte
content = ReadByteArrFromFile("C:\Users\me\Desktop\Folder\document.docx")
FileName = "document.docx"
arg = "{""path"":""/Work/" & FileName & """,""mode"":{"".tag"":""add""},""autorename"":true,""mute"":false}"
req.Open "POST", "https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload", False
req.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer xxxxx"

req.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/octet-stream"
req.setRequestHeader "Content-length", Len(Result)
req.setRequestHeader "Dropbox-API-Arg", arg
req.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "api-explorer-client"
req.Send content

If req.Status = 200 Then '200 = OK
    'MsgBox req.Status & ": " & req.StatusText
    Debug.Print req.responseText
Else
    MsgBox req.Status & ": " & req.StatusText
    Debug.Print req.responseText
End If
End Sub

Function ReadByteArrFromFile(filePath) As Byte()
    Dim buff() As Byte
    Dim fileNumb As Integer
    fileNumb = FreeFile
    Open filePath For Binary Access Read As fileNumb
    ReDim buff(0 To LOF(fileNumb) - 1)
    Get fileNumb, , buff
    Close fileNumb
    ReadByteArrFromFile = buff
End Function
```

Comment: Are you setting Content-length correctly?

Comment: What is `Result` the variable is not defined (unless it is global). Please clarify and make sure you use `Option Explicit`. You probably meant to use `Len(content)` instead of `Len(Result)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the correct `Content-length` value:

```vb
    Dim arg As String
    Dim content As Byte, fPath as string
    
    fPath = "C:\Users\me\Desktop\Folder\document.docx"
    
    FileName = "document.docx"
    
    arg = "{""path"":""/Work/" & FileName & """,""mode"":{"".tag"":""add""},""autorename"":true,""mute"":false}"
    
    req.Open "POST", "https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload", False
    req.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer xxxxx"
    
    req.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/octet-stream"
    req.setRequestHeader "Content-length", FileLen(fPath) '<<< set the correct size
    req.setRequestHeader "Dropbox-API-Arg", arg
    req.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "api-explorer-client"
    req.Send ReadByteArrFromFile(fPath)
    
    If req.Status = 200 Then '200 = OK
        'MsgBox req.Status & ": " & req.StatusText
        Debug.Print req.responseText
    Else
        MsgBox req.Status & ": " & req.StatusText
        Debug.Print req.responseText
    End If

End Sub
```